# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' ',on tkinter entry and Postgresql database

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I tried to operate on tkinter entry ...
The value of that entry is used as integer type in the database..
I converted my entry value to integer as follows...

> self.yr=(int(self.year.get()))
>
> self.isb=(int(self.isbn.get()))

eventhough it throws ValueError..

How to convert string value from an ENTRY WIDGET to an integer value to be used as an argument for my search function in Postgresql database..

My Backend search function is: here in the code..[year,isbn are integer values]

```
def search(self,title=None,author=None,year=None,isbn=None):
        self.cur.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE title=%s or author=%s or year=%s or isbn=%s",(title,author,year,isbn))
        row=self.cur.fetchall()
        return row
```

My Frontend code is:

```
from tkinter import *
from books_db import database

db=database()
class Window(object):
    def __init__(self,window):
            self.window=window
            self.window.wm_title("BOOK STORE")

    #############  ENTRIES.................
            self.title=Entry(window)
            self.title.grid(row=0,column=1)


            self.year=Entry(window)
            self.year.grid(row=1,column=1)
            self.yr=(int(self.year.get()))

            self.author=Entry(window)
            self.author.grid(row=0,column=3)


            self.isbn=Entry(window)
            self.isbn.grid(row=1,column=3)
            self.isb=(int(self.isbn.get()))

    ############  LISTBOX.................
            self.list=Listbox(window,height=6,width=35)
            self.list.grid(row=2,column=0,rowspan=6,columnspan=2)

    ########## BUTTONS...............

            b2=Button(window,text="SEARCH ENTRY",width=15,command=self.search_cmd)
            b2.grid(row=3,column=3)


    def search_cmd(self):
           self.list.delete(0,END)
           for item in db.search(self.title.get(),self.author.get(),self.yr,self.isb):
               self.list.insert(END,item)



window=Tk()
Window(window)
window.mainloop()
```

[image: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' ',on tkinter entry and Postgresql database]

Comment: Like your error message says, the null-string `''` cannot be converted... Type something in and it should work. Or implement some speical handling for that case.

Comment: I want to make search over my table as mentioned in the code above  [title(text),author(text),year(integer),isbn(integer)]. The search is made using  any of the values among the four columns.If i make search using any one of the values ..it throws ValueError..How to make search using any one of the ENTRY WIDGETS..??

Comment: That's at best a separate question.

Answer (score 3):

Consider these three lines of code:

```
self.isbn=Entry(window)
self.isbn.grid(row=1,column=3)
self.isb=(int(self.isbn.get()))
```

You are creating a `Entry` widget, and about a microsecond later you are getting the value and converting it to an int. The user will not have even seen the entry widget, much less typed into it. Thus, the value will be the empty string, and the call to `int()` will fail.

Your code must wait to call `get()` until after the user has had a chance to enter data.

Comment: """def search_cmd(self):
           self.i=int(self.isb.get())
           self.y=int(self.yr.get())
           self.list.delete(0,END)
           for item in db.search(self.title.get(),self.author.get(),self.y,self.i):
               self.list.insert(END,item)""""  If I do that inside search function as stated above ...that to ends with same error