# Calculating totals from entries in GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

Struggling with making this code work in my GUI. I am overloaded with errors and trying to understand syntactically how I can make this work. I am trying to make an order form that takes the number of cookies a customer wants and computes their total. I know that this certainly has to be some simple thing I'm overlooking.

```
from tkinter import Button, Entry, Label,Tk
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo

class CookieOrderForm(Tk):

    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.title("Cookie Form")
        self.make_widgets()

    def total(self):
        order = sum(int(e.get()) for e in (self.chipEn, self.oatEn, self.oreoEn))
        txt = ("Your Order Total Is: " + str(order))
        self.new.config(text = txt)
        
        

    def make_widgets(self):
        chip = Label(self, text='Chocolate Chip ($1.00)').grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.chipEn = Entry(self)
        self.chipEn.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=4)
        oat = Label(self, text='Oatmeal ($1.50)').grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.oatEn = Entry(self)
        self.oatEn.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=4)       
        Button(self,text='Order Total', command=lambda:self.total()).grid(row=4, column=2)
        oreo = Label(self, text='Oreo ($2.00)').grid(row=3, column=0)
        self.oreoEn = Entry(self)
        self.oreoEn.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=4)
        self.new = Label(self)
        self.new.grid(row=3, column=1)

CookieOrderForm().mainloop()
```

I think my main issue is coming from this line here
`order = sum(int(e.get()) for e in (self.chipEn, self.oatEn, self.oreoEn))`

EDIT:::: Error Messages Included

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\17734\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1884, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\17734\OneDrive\Desktop\fall 2021\csc242\homework\CSC242hw4.py", line 91, in <lambda>
    Button(self,text='Order Total', command=lambda:self.total()).grid(row=4, column=2)
  File "C:\Users\17734\OneDrive\Desktop\fall 2021\csc242\homework\CSC242hw4.py", line 78, in total
    order = sum(int(e.get()) for e in (self.chipEn, self.oatEn, self.oreoEn))
  File "C:\Users\17734\OneDrive\Desktop\fall 2021\csc242\homework\CSC242hw4.py", line 78, in <genexpr>
    order = sum(int(e.get()) for e in (self.chipEn, self.oatEn, self.oreoEn))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: So what exactly goes wrong when you run this code?  "I am overloaded with errors" doesn't tell us anything.

Comment: Ahhh sorry, forgot about the important part. Going to add the error messages to my original post. Just looking for a way to rework my code to get past these errors.

Comment: on python3.9  (or any python version) I cannot reproduce those errors. this post might be useful or related: [ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' ',on tkinter entry and Postgresql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47714032/valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10-on-tkinter-entry-and-pos)

Comment: you should check what you have in variables. Error can means that you have empty string in some `Entry` and you try to convert `int("")` which gives your error. SO you could first check if all values are different then `""`  or you should sum value in `try/except` to catch error. This can be useful because someone can also put text - ie. `Hello World` - instead number and you also get error.

Answer (score 0):

You may get this error only if you have empty `Entry` when you press `Button`.

Try `int("")` and you see the same error.

You may get similar error when you put some text (like `Hello World`) instead number.

You could put `sum()` in `try/except` to catch errors.

```
    def total(self):
        try:
            order = sum(int(e.get()) for e in (self.chipEn, self.oatEn, self.oreoEn))
            txt = ("Your Order Total Is: " + str(order))
        except Exception as ex:
            print('Exception:', ex)
            txt = 'Your have wrong values in Order'

        self.new.config(text = txt)
```

Eventually you should convert every value separatelly in separated `try/catch` to see which `Entry` has wrong value and display message with better information.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best solution but it works.
Added function to check if your input is a digit, if not it will return `0` if yes it will return `int`

````
from tkinter import Button, DoubleVar, Entry, Label, StringVar,Tk
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo


class CookieOrderForm(Tk):

    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.title("Cookie Form")
        self.make_widgets()

    def entryIsDigit(self, number: str) -> int:
        if number.isdigit() == True:
            return int(number)
        return 0

    def total(self):
        order = sum(e for e in (self.entryIsDigit(self.chipEn.get()), self.entryIsDigit(self.oatEn.get()), self.entryIsDigit(self.oreoEn.get())))
        txt = ("Your Order Total Is: " + str(order))
        self.new.config(text = txt)
        
        

    def make_widgets(self):
        chip = Label(self, text='Chocolate Chip ($1.00)').grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.chipEn = Entry(self)
        self.chipEn.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=4)
        oat = Label(self, text='Oatmeal ($1.50)').grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.oatEn = Entry(self)
        self.oatEn.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=4)       
        Button(self,text='Order Total', command=lambda:self.total()).grid(row=4, column=2)
        oreo = Label(self, text='Oreo ($2.00)').grid(row=3, column=0)
        self.oreoEn = Entry(self)
        self.oreoEn.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=4)
        self.new = Label(self)
        self.new.grid(row=3, column=1)

CookieOrderForm().mainloop()```
````

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working under Python 3.11 or 3.12. Currently, using Python 3.12.1 will give you bug-free.

There are two (2) grid layout managers who are wrong.

- `Button(self,text='Order Total', command=lambda:self.total()).grid(row=5,..)` instead of `row=4`.
- `self.new.grid(row=4, column=1)` instead of `row=3`.

Screenshot:

[image]